# irrlicht model loading/animating

Tags: c++, animation, textures, mesh, irrlicht

I've been trying (for hours now) to get a b3d model loaded, shown and animated properly.
The model has an animation between frames 0 and 45, it was made and painted (the whole kit) in blender as testing model. Only half of the model is shown, it's completely white and it doesn't move.
I've been googling on information on loading b3d into irrlicht and it's animation system, but trying to load texture from the b3d file failed and all other information I incorporated into the program.

[Here](http://picpaste.com/af00c9fec265405db3890aa86e14d661.jpg) is the link to the picture of the actual result.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/tyMfJ8GR) is the link to the code (shortened with comments on the insignificant parts).

Comment: Try to ask this question in the Irrlicht forums, you might have better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you correctly define 'node'? If not, try this:

```
IAnimatedMeshSceneNode* node = smgr->addAnimatedMeshSceneNode (smgr->getMesh ("mesh.b3d"));
```

If you added the node as an `IMeshSceneNode` the animations will not show. As for the texturing, I believe with `irrlicht` you must set all textures manually. Try this in the 'if (node)' block:

```
node->setMaterialTexture (0, driver->getTexture ("texture.bmp"));
```

Comment: I changed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some painting tools doesn't appear on the model when exported via Blender.
You may've used some, try looking up any possible issues with the tools you used on the net.

Also you sure that you light the model ?
That may cause problems too.

I'm in a bit hurry atm couldn't check the code, I may look deeply later.
Hope it solves